# How to use pagination on an array of arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I added the following arrays into `all_updates[]` as follows :

```
$all_updates[] = $all_update_in;
$all_updates[] = $all_update_out;
$all_updates[] = $all_update_oth;
```

The `$all_updates` output :

> array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#365 (21) { ["id"]=> int(84) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-31 12:24:28" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-31 12:24:28" ["title"]=> string(14) "the tag newest" ["body"]=> string(20) "the tag newest ANSWER" } } }

I'm trying to paginate the final array as follows :

```
$Final_array= $all_updates->paginate(15);
```

I'm receiving the following error :

> Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Comment: the `paginate()` function is specific to query builder objects, you can't call it on arrays

Comment: If you post your full code, maybe we can give a better advice. Because, we need to know why you combine `$all_update_in`, `$all_update_out`, `$all_update_oth` after you separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not paginate an array. You paginate the output of the query which is stored in an array but not the array itself.

That means that your 3 nested arrays should already be paginated before inserted in the parent array.

After that you loop around them and you get the `links` field. This is your pagination info.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to convert the array to collection using `collect($arr)`

Then check hakob93 answer on the following thread to move forward:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-laravel-collection?page=1#reply=363252

Answer (score 1):

paginate() function is query builder that's why you can't use here .

but you can do with take() and slice().

like

```
$skipRow=0;

$data=[
  [
    'id'=>1,
    'name'=>'suresh'
  ]
  [
    'id'=>2,
    'name'=>'mahesh'
  ]
];

$collectedData=collect($data);

$rowData=$collectedData->slice($skipRow)->take(15);
```